# Serialize MYSQL_RES

Tags: mysql, c++

I have 2 servers (One for Database Connections and one or more for client connections) running in a machine. The job of the database connections server is to fetch data from MySQL database (`Aurora`) and give this to the other servers on request.

Right now the data transfer (Between the 2 servers) happens via Json (json_spirit)(Don't know why I designed it this way.).

I am coming up to a stage where the data that is loaded from the MySQL DB is huge when the server starts up and every 1 minute. And 1000s of smaller queries in between.

I can see the impact `Json` is having since I have to Parse `MYSQL_RES` to `Json` and transmit from the DB Connection server to Client connection server and then parse the `Json` to a data set. I am looking to serialize my data or do something other than parsing since the overhead is slowing down the client connection server since it is waiting on the response from DB Connection Server.

What would you suggest to serialize `MYSQL_RES` struct? I have read about `Protobuf`, `Flatbuffer` and `serialization`. But simply cannot make a decision.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign.

The clients should access the database directly.  This is much lighter weight than going through a "server".

No, don't argue that you have to keep the current architecture.  You will simply be making more work for yourself now *and in the future*.

Comment: The reason for this is to be asynchronous. Mysql cpp lib did not support async calls when we where designing.

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan - Please elaborate on the need for async.  You can simply have multiple connections, each running separately.

Comment: DB connections need to be async. The main code should not block because of Mysql connections .That was the main issue.

Comment: For web applications, any query taking more than a few dozen milliseconds need to be optimized.

Comment: My code cannot wait for few dozen milliseconds. All my queries take 10-30ms and 50 at max for bookkeeping queries. An async server does not have that much time to wait for a response. That is why this entire architecture was built. So that the Database server can be blocking on mysql calls and the main server is connected to the DB Server asynchronously.

Comment: Think that my code is trying to achieve c10k. So each ms is valuable.

Comment: In AJAX-like communication, it is virtually impossible to do _synchronous_ calls back to the server.  That is async is the only thing available.  Are we talking about different situations?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan - and is nginx involved?

Comment: My server connects to 10000s of client devices and routinely does stuff. Keeps the devices synced with DB etc. Completely C++.

Comment: Is "do stuff" effectively "fetch one number" or maybe "fetch several readings" and then store them into table(s)?  What the total number of `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs` per day?  How frequently do you poll each 'device' -- once a minute?  once an hour?  other?

Answer (score 1):

> loaded from the MySQL DB is huge when the server starts up and every 1 minute.

If that is the main problem, then the solution is to use replication to keep the recipient server up to date *without having to do a full copy*.

Writes to the Master are 'replicated', as they happen, to the Replica.  If the replicas become overworked, you can add more replicas, thereby spreading the load out.

Effectively, replication can provide a virtually infinite *read* capacity.  (*Write* capacity is not helped.)

To discuss this, and other options, please provide more details on the flow of data, including frequency and other metrics.  (For example, it is trivial to poll 10K devices evenly spread out across a day, but "impossible" to poll 10k devices at exactly midnight.)